# Storing match from grep in variable

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I have the following extension: 
"/home/eg/Download/jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz"

I now want to pass the "jdk-8u20" to a separate variable.

the relevant regex in JS would be `/jdk\-[0-9]u[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?/`

and I can get grep to acknowledge the data in question when i run the following on the command prompt:

```
test="/home/eg/Download/jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz"
grep jdk\-[0-9]u[0-9][0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]* <(echo "$test")
```

but I can't figure out how to get that "jdk-8u20" into another variable!

i've tried

```
test1=${grep jdk\-[0-9]u[0-9][0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]* <(echo "$test")}
```

but echo $test1 just returns the full file path. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the pattern within quotes and also you need to enable `-o` (*show only the part of a line matching PATTERN*) parameter.

```
$ test="/home/eg/Download/jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz"
$ test1=$(grep -o 'jdk-[0-9]u[0-9][0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*' <<< $test)
$ echo $test1
jdk-8u20
```

Answer (score 2):

You need quotes around your grep pattern and `-o` to print only the matched part of the string.

Simplified:

```
$ test="/home/eg/Download/jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz"
$ test1=$(grep -o 'jdk-[^-]*' <<< $test)
$ echo $test1
jdk-8u20
```